# Parse JSON message that contains multiple events in Logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I was wondering how to parse JSON message that contains multiple events in Logstash. As an example like this JSON message:

```
{
    "Records": [
    {
        "eventVersion": "1.03",
        "userIdentity": {
            "type": "IAMUser",
            "principalId": "111122223333",
            "arn": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/myUserName",
            "accountId": "111122223333",
            "accessKeyId": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE",
            "userName": "myUserName"
        },
        "eventTime": "2015-08-26T20:46:31Z",
        "eventSource": "s3.amazonaws.com",
        "eventName": "DeleteBucketPolicy",
        "awsRegion": "us-west-2",
        "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1",
        "userAgent": "[]",
        "requestParameters": {
            "bucketName": "myawsbucket"
        },
        "responseElements": null,
        "requestID": "47B8E8D397DCE7A6",
        "eventID": "cdc4b7ed-e171-4cef-975a-ad829d4123e8",
        "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
        "recipientAccountId": "111122223333"
    },
    {
       "eventVersion": "1.03",
       "userIdentity": {
            "type": "IAMUser",
            "principalId": "111122223333",
            "arn": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/myUserName",
            "accountId": "111122223333",
            "accessKeyId": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE",
            "userName": "myUserName"
        },
      "eventTime": "2015-08-26T20:46:31Z",
      "eventSource": "s3.amazonaws.com",
      "eventName": "PutBucketAcl",
      "awsRegion": "us-west-2",
      "sourceIPAddress": "",
      "userAgent": "[]",
      "requestParameters": {
          "bucketName": "",
          "AccessControlPolicy": {
              "AccessControlList": {
                  "Grant": {
                      "Grantee": {
                          "xsi:type": "CanonicalUser",
                          "xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
                          "ID": "d25639fbe9c19cd30a4c0f43fbf00e2d3f96400a9aa8dabfbbebe1906Example"
                       },
                      "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
                   }
              },
              "xmlns": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/",
              "Owner": {
                  "ID": "d25639fbe9c19cd30a4c0f43fbf00e2d3f96400a9aa8dabfbbebe1906Example"
              }
          }
      },
      "responseElements": null,
      "requestID": "BD8798EACDD16751",
      "eventID": "607b9532-1423-41c7-b048-ec2641693c47",
      "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
      "recipientAccountId": "111122223333"
    },
    {
      "eventVersion": "1.03",
      "userIdentity": {
          "type": "IAMUser",
          "principalId": "111122223333",
          "arn": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/myUserName",
          "accountId": "111122223333",
          "accessKeyId": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE",
          "userName": "myUserName"
        },
      "eventTime": "2015-08-26T20:46:31Z",
      "eventSource": "s3.amazonaws.com",
      "eventName": "GetBucketVersioning",
      "awsRegion": "us-west-2",
      "sourceIPAddress": "",
      "userAgent": "[]",
      "requestParameters": {
          "bucketName": "myawsbucket"
      },
      "responseElements": null,
      "requestID": "07D681279BD94AED",
      "eventID": "f2b287f3-0df1-4961-a2f4-c4bdfed47657",
      "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
      "recipientAccountId": "111122223333"
    }
  ]
}
```

my logstash configuration for the filter is as follow:

```
filter{

if [type] == "s3-log"{
        json{
                source => "message"
                }
        split{
                field => "Records"
        }
}

}
```

Can logstash's json filter plugin help to differentiate different events in this JSON message?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Interested if you got anywhere, having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `split` filter to split the `Records` field into multiple events.

```
split {
  field => "Records"
}
```

See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-split.html

Comment: i have tried to use the split as you suggested but it doesn't work, see my updated question for my filter configuration